# Перебор цифр. Алгоритмы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Имеется n цифр (естественно не больше 10). Нужно написать программу, которая (ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО) выведет все варианты комбинации цифр. Цифры не могут повторяться.
Например, для n = 9 вывод

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1
0 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2
. . . . .
```

и т.д.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надеюсь, вы знаете, что то, что вам нужно - это генерация всех *перестановок*. Каковая в C++ осуществляется функциями `next_permutation`/`prev_permutation`.

```
string s = "012345678";
do {
    cout << s << endl;
while( next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end()));
```